# activemq network of brokers missing username or password

Tags: activemq-classic

I'm trying to set a network of brokers in activemq, my current setup is having two brokers each running on a different vm. My configuration is:

```
<networkConnectors>
     <networkConnector
        name="Q:broker1->broker2"
        uri="static:(tcp://10.10.10.12:61612)"
        duplex="false"
        decreaseNetworkConsumerPriority="true"
        networkTTL="2"
        dynamicOnly="true"
        userName="activemq"
        password="password">
        <excludedDestinations>
              <topic physicalName=">" />
        </excludedDestinations>
     </networkConnector>
 </networkConnectors>
```

I'm getting this error when I start up activemq on broker1:

```
2016-11-01 17:49:18,571 | INFO  | Establishing network connection from vm://localhost?create=false&async=false to tcp://10.10.10.12:61612 | org.apache.activemq.network.DiscoveryNetworkConnector | ActiveMQ Task-1
2016-11-01 17:49:18,572 | INFO  | Connector vm://localhost started | org.apache.activemq.broker.TransportConnector | ActiveMQ Task-1
2016-11-01 17:49:18,578 | WARN  | Failed to add Connection localhost->localhost-34161-1478036807089-20:1 due to java.lang.SecurityException: User name [activemq] or password is invalid. | org.apache.activemq.broker.TransportConnection | triggerStartAsyncNetworkBridgeCreation: remoteBroker=tcp:///10.10.10.12:61612@43981, localBroker= vm://localhost#18
2016-11-01 17:49:18,580 | WARN  | Security Error occurred on connection to: vm://localhost#18, User name [activemq] or password is invalid. | org.apache.activemq.broker.TransportConnection.Service | triggerStartAsyncNetworkBridgeCreation: remoteBroker=tcp:///10.10.10.12:61612@43981, localBroker= vm://localhost#18
2016-11-01 17:49:18,580 | INFO  | Network connection between vm://localhost#18 and tcp:///10.10.10.12:61612@43981 shutdown due to a local error: java.lang.SecurityException: User name [activemq] or password is invalid. | org.apache.activemq.network.DemandForwardingBridgeSupport | triggerStartAsyncNetworkBridgeCreation: remoteBroker=tcp:///10.10.10.12:61612@43981, localBroker= vm://localhost#18
2016-11-01 17:49:18,583 | INFO  | Connector vm://localhost stopped | org.apache.activemq.broker.TransportConnector | ActiveMQ BrokerService[localhost] Task-8
2016-11-01 17:49:18,584 | INFO  | localhost bridge to localhost stopped | org.apache.activemq.network.DemandForwardingBridgeSupport | ActiveMQ BrokerService[localhost] Task-8
2016-11-01 17:49:20,580 | INFO  | Stopping vm://localhost#18 because Failed with SecurityException: User name [activemq] or password is invalid. | org.apache.activemq.broker.TransportConnection | ActiveMQ BrokerService[localhost] Task-5
```

I set the activemq user in broker2 activemq.xml like the following:

```
<simpleAuthenticationPlugin>
                    <users>
                        <authenticationUser username="activemq" password="${activemq.password}"
                            groups="admins"/>
```

and the user activemq is defined in credentials-enc.properties file like:

```
activemq.password=password
```

why broker1 is enable to establish a connection with broker2? what I'm missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the userName and password attributes like this:

```
<networkConnector .. userName="admin" password="admin".. >
```

[Network Connector Properties](http://activemq.apache.org/networks-of-brokers.html)

Part 2:

Do you have a property placeholder bean in your activemq.xml file? You need that for the macro replacement to work. Otherwise, the broker probably thinks the password is literally the text below with the $ sign and { }  braces.

```
${activemq.password}
```

Comment: thanks Matt for your reply.. please see my updated question